# Scraping of the Twitter follower page using selenium and phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, phantomjs

I am trying to get the follower list of a given Twitter account. To do so, I manage to connect to my account using Selenium and PhantomJS (v2.1.1).
Then, since Twitter is using infinite scrolling, I would like to implement the following algorithm:

```
1/ Count the number of html elements with class attribute equals ProfileCard-screennameLink 

2/ Repeat:
    -Scroll down
    -Count the number of html elements with class attribute equals ProfileCard-screennameLink
Until the number of elements does not change
```

My problem is that the scrolling function does not work. Indeed, when I am running

```
    elemsCount = browser.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('.ProfileCard-screennameLink').length")
    print("c", elemsCount)

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(10)
    elemsCount = browser.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('.ProfileCard-screennameLink').length")
    print("c (new)", elemsCount)
```

There is no change in the number of retrieved HTML elements (neither in the height of the page).. It looks like the `scrollTo` function has no impact. 
Do you have any explanation or workaround to solve my problem please?

Comment: Why aren't you using any of the numerous twitter modules for Python, such as [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/)?

Comment: One part of my project is using Tweepy (to get the current trends) but the point is that due to the API rate limit and since I would like to collect the followers of quite numerous accounts, using Tweepy is not relevant to me in this scenario.

Comment: If twitter will rate limit you via their API, you can bet they won't want you harvesting that much data from their website either.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but that's not the point. I do succeed when using Safari as the web driver for Selenium. My problem is when using PhantomJS instead of Safari (and I do need to use PhantomJS since the server I plan running my code on has not installed server X).

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution @YoannPitarch ?

Comment: @A.Attia Unfortunately no... Sorry